# Augmenting Psi-like abilities

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, dreamscarred-press

I was making a creature for my game and wanted to give it the feat Psionic Awakening. This gives it the ability to manifest one of three powers as a Psi-like ability (in this case *inertial armor*), with a manifester level equal to their character level. If the Psi-like is manifested, does it get automatically augmented as if PP were spent on it, or is it just the base power?

I'm aware of the question [Can Psi-like abilities be augmented with power points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35136/can-psi-like-abilities-be-augmented-with-power-points), which explains that in 3.5, Psi-likes are automatically augmented up to the manifester level for free, but there the 3.5 SRD explicitly says:

> the power is manifested as if the creature had spent a number of power points equal to its manifester level, which may augment the power...

By comparison, the definitions for Psi-likes in Ultimate Psionics says

> A psionic effect which can be manifested without paying a power point cost. When manifesting a psi-like ability, the creature's effective manifester level is equal to its hit dice unless specified otherwise...

It never actually says that any points are spent to augment or that it's treated as if points were spent to augment the power.

So is my *inertial armor* Psi-like stuck at +4 armor bonus, or is it augmented through some errata/clarification I may have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I freelanced for Dreamscarred Press for a while—I am absolutely certain that no one on that team intended to change how psi-like abilities are augmented relative to 3.5e. In fact, I could swear it’s in there somewhere, though a quick search doesn’t find it so perhaps I am mistaken there. Fact remains that this definitely was not an intentional omission; just an oversight.